# Interaction Variable Interpretation

Tags: regression, interpretation, regression-coefficients

I am running a wage regression on Stata and need help on some variable interpretation. My dependent variable is log hourly wages, so I know I need to interpret in %.

2 of my variables are:

- Number of dependent children: coefficient of -0.011
- Female*Number of dependent children: coefficient of -0.012

How do I interpret these - do I interpret them together or seperately?

Would the interpretation be:

- For every additional child the individual has, their hourly wages are 0.011% lower, with all other characteristics remaining constant.
- For every additional child the individual has, women's hourly wages are 0.012% lower compared to male's hourly wages, with all other characteristics remaining constant.

Thank you!

Comment: Why would you interpret log-values as percentages? What model are you using, OLS? If so, then log-wages are just that, $log(wage)$, not a percentage, in which case you would interpret the coefficients like with any OLS estimation, i.e. $\hat \beta$ (e.g. your -0.011) is by how much your response changes on average if the regressor increases by 1 unit (given the model is correctly specified).

Comment: Yes OLS. I thought it was standard to interpret in % when the dependent variable has a log transformation.

Comment: You are probably confusing OLS with logistic regression, where probabilities (%) are predicted from log-odds. That is however a completely different method, usually solved via MLE (not LS), for when the response itself is a class (e.g. A or B). It's not just taking the log of y, which would still be a real valued random variable.

Comment: So your interpretation of the first coefficient would be correct if you replaced wages with log-wages and left the % out. Same with the second coefficient, except that it's *in addition* to log-wages of males. To get nornal wages first predict log-wages then exponentiate.

Comment: Ok, thanks Paul!